# AWS EC2: SFTP SSH2 Permission Denied

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sftp, bitnami, ssh2-sftp

Some context: I am using Bitnami WordPress for AWS. It's on an EC2 instance. I have been using the same PEM file to both SSH & SFTP into the instance for a while and still do on several other instances without any problem using Yummy FTP Pro.

Issue: I went and did some cleanup to get rid of the excess themes WordPress has by default everything worked fine. Themes deleted. I must not have disconnected correctly or something before closing out of the SFTP program because now after I successfully SFTP in and only when I try to modify files I get the following error.

`Couldn't get handle : SSH2_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED - Permission denied`

I have been searching StackOverflow and googling a solution but coming up empty-handed with a solution to fix it.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. A question like this might be better off on [webapps.se], [wordpress.se], or [su]. When you move the question, you should include the username that you're using to access the remote site, the exact permissions on the file(s) that you're trying to modify, and a specific type of file modification which you're trying to do which produces the error. Your current description of the problem that you're having is really pretty vague.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Turns out Bitnami has several directories that look the same but you can only upload to one of them.